# How can we multiply the elements of a list by increasing the index?

Tags: python-3.x

```
b = [3,2,6]
hid = []

#print(b[0] * b[1])
#print(b[1] * b[2])
#print(b[2] * b[3])
for n in range(len(b)):
    print(b[n-1] * b[n])
```

The result I am expecting is

```
6, 12
```

But I am getting

```
18,  6, 12
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Your list has three elements only, so there's no `b[3]`, what you're trying to achieve (multiplying combinations of size `2`) can be done using two nested loops:

```
b = [3, 2, 6]

for i in range(len(b) - 1):
  for j in range(i + 1, len(b)):
    print(b[i] * b[j])
```

Output:

```
6
18
12
```

However, a more Pythonic way would be to use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
b = [3, 2, 6]

from itertools import combinations

for x, y in combinations(b, 2):
  print(x * y)
```

Output:

```
6
18
12
```

Answer (score 0):

**range(len(b))** which evaluate as (0,1,2)
so **b[n-1]** is **b[-1]** which is **6** so **(6** * **3)** =**18** it give result

```
18,  6, 12
```

try This one:

```
for n in range(len(b)-1):
    print(b[n] * b[n+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in range(len(b)):
    print(b[n-1] * b[n])
```

in first iteration when n =0 you have:

```
print(b[n-1] * b[n])
```

what means:

```
print(b[0-1] * b[0])
```

b[0-1] will gave you last element in the list, because of that you have

```
6*3 = 18
```

you should do it:

```
b = [3,2,6]
hid = []

for n in range(1,len(b)):
    print(b[n-1] * b[n])
```

> range(3) will generate numbers from 0 to 2 (3 numbers). You can also
>   define the start, stop and step size as range(start,stop,step size).
>   step size defaults to 1 if not provided.

or

```
b = [3,2,6]
hid = []

for n in range(len(b)-1):
    print(b[n] * b[n+1])
```

output:

```
6
12
```

Answer (score 0):

In a for loop, the iteration starts at `zero`

```
for n in range(len(b)):
```

`print(b[n-1] * b[n])` doing "n-1" means b[-1] which is last element of your list "6" and this with b[n] which b[0] is 18.

So, your code translates to :

```
print b[-1]*b[0]
print b[0]*b[1]
print b[1]*b[2]
```

Correct way to code this would be :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

b = [3,2,6]
i = 0
while i < len(b)-1:
    print b[i]*b[i+1]
    i+=1
```

Output:

```
6
12
```